# input button won't work in IE 7 or 8

Tags: button, input, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I was asked to fix some probs on a site. This one has me stumped.
The Reserverien button (link) will not work in IE 7 or 8, it's fine in IE9 and all other browsers and when I replace the button with a simple text link. DTD was strict so I changed it to transitional & got it to validate to no avail.
Here's a link to a test page:
http://www.allacantina.ch/de/unterkunft/test.html 
the offending line is:

```
<a href="http://www.tomas.ch/irs/TBooking/start.jsp?CFID=ETLM&amp;MODULE=MOD_VAC&amp;SPID=TDS00020010133846091&amp;LANG=de" target="_blank"><input name="Reservieren" type="button" value="Reservieren" /></a>
```

PS I did not design this site!

Help as ever is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the `<button>` tag, it isn't guaranteed what gets sent in the form. From the W3 site: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Tips and Notes

Important: If you use the  element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Internet Explorer, prior version 9, will submit the text between the  and  tags, while other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute. Use the  element to create buttons in an HTML form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the <button> tag got me half-way there, I needed to add some javascript as explained in this link:http://www.expertsguide.info/2010/07/button-tag-inside-anchor-not-working-in-i/